# Localhost is not accessible on LAN

Tags: angular-cli

I have done ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 command. And I am able to access my site using my local ip address 192.168.1.1:4200 using my own PC (sample). But I cannot access it from other computer or from tablet on the same network. My other site which is 192.168.1.1:8080 is accessible though

Comment: try `ng serve --host 192.168.1.1`

Comment: from a different PC on your network... you'd have to do your `http://Your-PC-network-IP:4200`

Comment: try running ipconfig(windows) or ifconfig(mac/linux) to get the IP

Comment: I tried the ng serve --host [my-ip] but still same result. On my own PC I am able to access using the IP, but from other's PC it is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the ports are being blocked by my firewall.

Answer (score -1):

The local host is only local. which means your pc only. If you want to run it to your LAN pc means. you should run it in the host. like below

```
ng serve --host [youe-IP]
```

Then open the LAN pc Browser user `[your-ip]:4200`

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But I have done this too, still no effect. On my own PC, I am able to access using the IP, but from other's PC it is not accessible.